# C# XMLSerializer and sequence of attribute serialization

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have a problem with XML deserialization. Well, lets suppose that my class have three properties:

```
public class Order
{
    private string name;
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private string tid;
    [XmlAttribute("TID")]
    public string TID
    {
        get
        {
            return tid;
        }
        set
        {
            if (tid != value)
            {
                tid = value;
            }
        }
    }


    private Command command;
    [XmlAttribute("Command")]
    public string Command
    {
        get
        {
            return command.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            command = new Command(TID, Name, value);
        }
    }

    public Order()
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to create an object Command with parameter constructor on deserialize Command property - but I need TID and Name attribute to this. I need to be sure that these fields are not null. As I observed, XmlSerializer is deserializing attributes according to sequence how user write it. For example:

```
<Order Command="SetPlus" TID="W403" Name="SomeName" />
```

In this case, first serialized will be Command attribute. But I don't have TID and Name property yet! I can't trust user that he will pass attributes in correct sequence like:

```
<Order TID="W403" Name="SomeName" Command="SetPlus" />
```

Well, I need some event or something I can call on deserialize finish OR I need to be sure that XmlSerializer will deserialize attributes in sequence like I want. The only thing I found is:

```
[XmlElement(Order = 1)]
```

or

```
[XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
```

But it doesn't work with XmlAttribute.

Is some way to do this? Hope I explained my problem clearly.

Comment: Are you using Order property on all the public members?

Answer (score 2):

If your `Command` only depends on the `TID` and the `Name` why do you even serialize it? 
This is just redundant information.

You should use the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute on the `Command`  property.
After that you can implement a kind of lazy load method for your `Command` property.

By the way: Your code is wrong anyway. On the `set` part of your `Command` property, you don't even use the value the user passed in.
It would be better if you'd do it like this:

```
private Command command;
[XmlIgnore]
public string Command
{
    get
    {
      if (command == null)
      {
        command = new Command(TID, Name));
      }
      return command.Name;
    }
}
```

edit:

ok after you changed your post and actually use the value of the `Command` property setter, the solution is a little trickier and there are multiple ways.

What I'd probably do:

- Add another property called `CommandName` to your class, which just is a simple string property (with getter), also add and `XmlAttribute` to this property
- Add the `[XmlIgnore]` to your `Command` property, and take my code from above (lazy initialization), return the command using the new `CommandName` property (`new Command(TID, Name, CommandName)`)

Personally I would even add a setter to the `CommandName` property and let the `Command` property actually return a `Command` and not a `string`. In my opinion this would make the code cleaner and more readable.

For clarification, this is how my class would look like:

```
public class Order
{
    //todo: if Name, TID or CommandName changes you'd have to initialize a new Command objects with the new values

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute("TID")]
    public string TID {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute("CommandName")]
    public string CommandName {get;set;}

    private Command command;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Command Command
    {
      get
      {
        return command ?? (command = new Command(TID, Name, CommandName));
      }
    }
    public Order()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: For that matter, why does it even have a setter?

Comment: I guess he is talking about deserialization not serialization.

Comment: Problem is more complicated. I give you very simple example to understand it and forgot to add 'value', like this:  command = new Command(TID, Name, value);

Comment: just realized the "bug" with the setter yet, I updated my answer with a (in my opinion) correct example.

Comment: Of course i'm using value, I just forgot to add it as a parameter to constructor. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put some logic in the setters so that when all the setters have been called you then create the command like so

```
public class Order
{
    private string name;
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                SetupCommandIfPossible();
            }

        }
    }

    private string tid;
    [XmlAttribute("TID")]
    public string TID
    {
        get
        {
            return tid;
        }
        set
        {
            if (tid != value)
            {
                tid = value;
                SetupCommandIfPossible();
            }
        }
    }


    private Command command;
    [XmlAttribute("Command")]
    public string Command
    {
        get
        {
            return command.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            SetupCommandIfPossible();
        }
    }

    public void SetupCommandIfPossible()
    {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tid) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && command == null)
         {             
            command = new Command(TID, Name);
         }
    }

    public Order()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, I was hope that is some more elegant solution. :(

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, its more testable than the attribute based method